# Group and sum columns based on values (Query)

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I would like to group and sum a table based on values (just like a pivot table would do, but without it) but without using it.

Example Table:
[image: Example table]

For example, in this query I would like to group each row that contains the same RU and TP and sum the Balance Value.
I tried using the group by like this Group by:

[image]

but it does not return every RU possible, if a value is in the TP column it does not appear in RU column.

EDIT1: My table starts like this

[image: my table]

and when I **group and sort** using group by in query the result is

[image: my table after group by]

the result is what I want, but as you can see, the `0156` and `0195` `RU`s, for some reason, are deleted from my table, and a lot of others `RU`s too.

Comment: Have you tried `SUMIFS()`?

Comment: Can you show what your desired output would look like and what the Group By is giving you?

Comment: @AlexisOlson I Edited the post to show you the output. The group by function works, but for some reason it hides a lot of RUs

Comment: Hmm. That's not the behavior I would expect. There must be something else going on. I'd need a reproducible example to be able to figure out what's happening.

Comment: I tried what you're doing with the subset of your table example in EDIT1 and noticed that when I sort on RU, it jumbles the order of the table; but if I then sort on TP too, it goes back to what I'd expect. Did you try that? That is, first sort Ascending on RU, then sort Ascending on TP also.